# Best line detector algorithm for a specific content bounding box measurement

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

The purpose of the algorithm is to auto align-sheet music pages based on staves/systems content.

The algorithm need to detect the bounding box [image: bounding box] to allow to easily compute the left/right and top/bottom margin for the wholes pages.

Current algorithm like morphological operations in openCV (using `cv2.HoughLinesP` for example) fails.

I need to found the most precise coordinates at least the top (first) or bottom (last) staff line and at least the left (systems) lines to compute the bounding box (red lines at left of the picture)

What is the state-of-the-art algorithm to work on this kind of document. The full resolution is in 600 dpi (5078 x 6566 pixels) if that can help (without downsizing).

Thank you very much.

Comment: there is a small "3" in the center right edge of the page. is that content or does that need to be excluded? -- hough isn't morphology. you don't care about lines, but about the bounding box. a box consists of lines but that doesn't make this a "line detection" problem. -- ***how*** do your previous attempts fail? show us the results and the code. -- there's no reason this shouldn't work with plain thresholding and getting the bounding box, perhaps with some added filtering for debris.

Comment: Maybe this question is suitable for [Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: I can offer a solution that yields https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVF6V.png

Comment: @LoverofStructure the "algorithm" tag led you to say that, right? computer science is math/logic (theoretical) or software engineering. this isn't any of that. this question is definitely not suitable for CS.SE

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz According to [this answer on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/188174), "Algorithms expressed in pseudocode straddle the border [between the Stack Overflow and Computer Science subsites]."

Comment: don't go by the letter, go by the intent. this question here, only this specific question, not any conceivable question tagged "algorithm", has nothing to do with CS, nor is "algorithm" central to the question or its solution. this question is clearly image processing/computer *vision*. let me present an analogy. chemistry isn't physics just because it consists of atoms. writing a specific recipe isn't "writing", even though it involves writing. the top voted answer to that question over there says "CS: For questions about computer science, as in the academic discipline". this is not that.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz You are perhaps right -- anyway, I didn't flag this question in any way, so I'll give it an upvote and leave it as is.

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz - the bounding box must only include the system/staves (staff lines) in order to exclude the upper text and the page number (the 3 in the center right). That mean that I only need a good algorithm to compute horizontal and vertical lines (but) keep only the "valid" ones. At least two lines with correct length are needed to compute the final bounding box (rectangle), one horizontal, one vertical. Or at least the upper left corner, and bottom right corner. The idea is to align multiples pages with the same content in term of sheet music staff lines.

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz - The attempt was using multiple "staff-line remover" algorithm (latest using hough) but the result content is not efficient to extract the needed coordinates (some lines extents the system + a lot of lines that are not consistents). Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Christop Rackwitz - Your solution (screenshot) is ok, because using the lower right corner and the full width can help to make a correct alignment over multiple page. Can you share an explaination ?

Comment: filtering for lines is done with morphology. you'd need one kernel for verticals and one for horizontals, then combine the results. this assumes the scan to be axis-aligned, not rotated too much.

Comment: here is the result of that: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jj5vP.png you'll notice the "stuff" that extends above the first and below the last "line". that can be handled with more severe filtering. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueFkK.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already looked into "staff-line removers". For this task, you need a part of that: the part that identifies staff lines.

Assuming the scan is upright, not rotated by a few degrees, that is usually done with morphology operations that use a "line" shaped kernel.

To also drop the short thick vertical bars on the left, your suggestion of a column histogram allows you to overcome the short horizontal stubs that connected those bars to the long vertical line.

1. threshold

```
level, mask = cv.threshold(
    src=im, thresh=128, maxval=255,
    type=cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv.THRESH_OTSU)
```

[image: thresholded]

2. morphology

```
hkernel = np.ones((1, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
vkernel = np.ones((3, 1), dtype=np.uint8)
horizontals = cv.morphologyEx(src=mask, op=cv.MORPH_OPEN, kernel=hkernel, iterations=50)
verticals = cv.morphologyEx(src=mask, op=cv.MORPH_OPEN, kernel=vkernel, iterations=40)
combined = horizontals | verticals
```

Tweak the kernel sizes and number of iterations.

[image: morphology]

3. bounding box

```
bbox = cv.boundingRect(combined)

canvas = cv.cvtColor(im >> 1, cv.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
cv.rectangle(img=canvas, rec=bbox, color=(0,255,0), thickness=1)
```

Includes the short stubs on the left edge.

[image: bbox]

4. column histogram to start the bounding box at the first long vertical

```
colhist = combined.mean(axis=0) / 255
colmax = colhist.max()
```

[image: plot]

```
# option: find global maximum
left = colhist.argmax()

# option: find first above threshold
indices, = np.where(colhist >= 0.5 * colmax)
left = indices[0]
```

fix the box up:

```
x0,y0,w,h = bbox
x1 = x0 + w # right edge stays where it is
bbox = (left, y0, x1 - left, h)
```

[image: fixed bbox]

5. shift the image so that the box is centered

```
x0,y0,w,h = bbox
bcenter = np.array([x0 + (w-1)/2, y0 + (h-1)/2])
icenter = np.array([(iw-1)/2, (ih-1)/2]) # image size

T = np.eye(3)
T[0:2, 2] = (+icenter - bcenter).round()

canvas = cv.warpAffine(
    src=canvas, M=T[:2], dsize=(iw, ih), flags=cv.INTER_NEAREST, borderMode=cv.BORDER_REPLICATE)
```

[image: centered]

This *will* be confused if there are any other long lines that aren't staff lines. That scan shows the bottom edge of the sheet of paper. You should make sure that either doesn't show up in the scan, or you need to erase image content near the edges (which is what I did here, without detailing it).

Comment: Oh. Thank you for the full code ! Very usefull. I've tested on full resolution pages (TIF 600 dpi), but seem the vertical iteration is too low and the bbox include the page number. So putting the vertical iteration to 20, the effect is interesting by excluding the text on top (chord name) and the text at the right (staff name).

Very close to the ideal bounding box. 

![original](https://i.postimg.cc/G2P7KRFr/page0027-denoised-deskewed.png)
![processed](https://i.postimg.cc/Y0pXyPRF/page0027-denoised-deskewed-bbox.png)

Thank you so much !!!

Comment: Maybe using this approach for getting the closest bounding box, I can add a similar approach of the staffline detection (by scanline histogram) to find the first inside "full" line right after the current coordinate ? The left boundary coordinate is already ok. Anyway, it's already a good apprimation ! Thanks

Comment: just increase the number of iterations roughly proportionally to the scale between low-res and full-res images. for a 3-sized kernel, number of iterations is roughly half the minimum feature length, so if you want to keep lines of at least 100 pixels, you'd need about 50 iterations. if the short thick vertical bars on the left need to be ignored too, just use more iterations on the vertical kernel. ideally, the filtering will only leave "full"-width and "full"-height lines.

Comment: the short thick vertical bars on the left are indeed a bit of a problem. even if they are filtered by the vertical filter, there are still some stubby horizontal lines left that connected them to the first long thin vertical. if you can rely on those pages always having that first long thin vertical, then yes, you can use a scanline (column) histogram to find it and use that as the left edge of the bounding box.

Comment: Oh cool. By putting 100 iterations on horizontal, I got this result : ![bounding box](https://i.postimg.cc/fLG3z3kj/page0082-denoised-deskewed-bbox.png), but yes, the left vertical system braces are problematic, even with 1000 vertical iteration, no change. So yes, maybe the histogram method to find the next vertical line that is > 33% of the detected bounding box height can be suitable for my purpose.

Comment: I've added code for that idea. it gives a good result.

Comment: That work very well !!! I've tested over a full book and this is perfect. I just need to understand the way to adapt the iterator values with the page size (that can be variable depend of book edition). 

And I need to found another algorithm before this processing to automatically remove some bad line artifacts on edges of the pages due to the scanner. I need to clean border to white color at least to a maximum distance to the page number (that can be sometimes close to the border). 

An idea to do something that can be used in your pipeline ?

Thank's a lot !!!